# How to use classes correctly in Android

Tags: android, class, nullpointerexception, findviewbyid

I'm new to programming and Android. I've built a small app for counting money.
It's just one big file at the moment with way to many methods in it.
So I thought I'd organize it a bit and go and put stuff in classes.
I have this clearAll method, which I put in a ClearAll class:

```
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ClearAll extends MainActivity {

    public void clearAll() {
        // Set EditTexts to ""
        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.euro500)).setText("");
        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.euro200)).setText("");
        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.euro100)).setText("");
        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.euro50)).setText("");
        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.euro20)).setText("");
        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.euro10)).setText("");
        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.euro5)).setText("");
        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.euro2)).setText("");
        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.euro1)).setText("");
        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.cent50)).setText("");
        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.cent20)).setText("");
        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.cent10)).setText("");
        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.cent5)).setText("");
        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.cent2)).setText("");
        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.cent1)).setText("");

        // Set TextViews to "0.00"
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEuro500Totaal)).setText(R.string.puntjes);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEuro200Totaal)).setText(R.string.puntjes);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEuro100Totaal)).setText(R.string.puntjes);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEuro50Totaal)).setText(R.string.puntjes);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEuro20Totaal)).setText(R.string.puntjes);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEuro10Totaal)).setText(R.string.puntjes);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEuro5Totaal)).setText(R.string.puntjes);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEuro2Totaal)).setText(R.string.puntjes);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEuro1Totaal)).setText(R.string.puntjes);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCent50Totaal)).setText(R.string.puntjes);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCent20Totaal)).setText(R.string.puntjes);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCent10Totaal)).setText(R.string.puntjes);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCent5Totaal)).setText(R.string.puntjes);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCent2Totaal)).setText(R.string.puntjes);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCent1Totaal)).setText(R.string.puntjes);

        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTotaalBedrag)).setText(R.string.puntjes);
    }
}
```

So in my MainActivity I do:

```
ClearAll clear = new ClearAll();
clear.clearAll();
```

But when that is called the app crashes with a NullPointerException on findViewById.
I've been searching for a while now and it has left me with more questions than when I started.
It seems that you can't use findViewById ouside the main activity because you haven't set setContentView().
Which I won't do since it's not the main activity.
I also tried to put a simple toast in a separate class and calling that, but that would crash as well.
So I'm just not doing it right.

Would anyone be willing to give me some pointers on how to correctly use classes in Android?

Cheers,

Daan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not about android, this is purely about java. You have to understand how instances work together.

Your ClearAll instance does not contain anything.

Your clearAll method must be in the scope on which it works. It uses findViewById, which indicates the scope should be the current activity.

The current activity is (i guess) the instance of MainActivity from where you call ClearAll.

There are several options :

1. put back clearAll in MainActivity
2. make ClearAll an abstract class that extends Activity. Make MainActivity extend ClearAll. From MainActivity, you can now call `this.clearAll()`
3. make ClearAll an abstract class that does not extend anything. make clearAll a static method that takes an Activity as a parameter. use this parameter to call findViewById on it. From MainActivity you can now call ClearAll.clearAll(this)

I recommend option 1. Option 2 and 3 are preferred if you'll use this method in several classes.

Also, as to reducing the amount of code, and, more importantly, of duplicated lines, I suggest making a Collection (array, list ...) of the ids for EditText and another one for the TextView, and looping on this collection to clear the content.

Something like (in MainActivity):

```
private final static int[] EDIT_IDS = new int[] {R.id.euro500, ... }
private final static int[] TEXT_IDS = new int[] {R.id.tvEuro500Totaal, ... }

private void clearAll() {
    for (int id : EDIT_IDS) {
        ((EditText) findViewById(id)).setText("");
    }
    for (int id : TEXT_IDS) {
        ((TextView) findViewById(id)).setText(R.string.puntjes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, I'll revert to how my code was and start experimenting with other methods by putting them into classes. I was already thinking about making a loop for the clearAll method. Big thanks for the example!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) in onCreate() then get id by findViewById() and then set text to null.

Since you have not set your layout , you cannot get the ids by findViewById().Hence you are getting nullpointerexception.

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            clearAll();
           }
       public void clearAll() {
         // Set EditTexts to ""
         ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.euro500)).setText("");
         ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.euro200)).setText("");

           }

   }
```

Comment: Yeah I know that was how I had it, and that worked fine. I'm trying to put it into a ClearAll class now.

Comment: Pragnani has provided you a solution